# How to identify which switch component has loaded in react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, switch-statement, components, react-props

I have a routing system in react, and a Layout component that wraps the system. 
I'm trying to figure out how to find out which route component was chosen in my Layout component

```
ReactDOM.render(
<BrowserRouter>
    <Layout>

            <Switch>
                <Route exact strict path={"/home"} component={home} />
                <Route exact path={"/page1"} component={page1} />
                <Route exact path={"/page2"} component={page2} />
                <Route exact path={"/page3"} component={page3}/>
                <Route exact path={"/page4"} component={page4}/>

            </Switch>

    </Layout>
    </BrowserRouter>
,document.getElementById('root'));
```

Is there some way to do something along the lines of 
`this.props.children.selectedRoute` in my `Layout Component` which would then return the component name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BrowserRouter` in `react-router-dom` uses React context to pass router context down the component tree.

A clean way to know what route is viewed is to have `Layout` hook into the provided router context.
You can do this by declaring `contextTypes` property for the `Layout` component as follows.

```
class Layout extends React.Component {
  static contextTypes = {
    router: PropTypes.object
  };

  render() {
    // Get the current path
    const { route: { location: { pathname } } } = this.context.router;
    const { children } = this.props;

    // Find child route that match current path.
    // This assumes that all routes are current children of the Layout, 
    // with a Switch use `children.props.children` instead of `children`
    // to find the selected route.
    const selectedRoute = children
                           .filter(route => route.props.path === pathname)
                           .pop();
    // continue play.

    return <div>{children}</div>
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Layout` is inside `BrowserRouter` and this is indeed possible.

All you have to do is wrap the `Layout` component inside `withRouter` higher order component.

`export default withRouter(Layout)`

and then, inside `Layout` you can access the router prop, [location](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/location)

```
function Layout({ location }) {
  if(location.pathname==="page1") {
    // Do something
  } else {
    // Other cases
  }
}
```